# Установка локального пакета через npm без интернета

Tags: npm

Возникла проблема при установки локального пакета через `npm`. Пробовал скопировать node_modules на машину без интернета, но `npm` встаёт на `idealTree:inflate` и дальше пишет ошибки `FetchError`. Если указать флаг `--offline`, то пишет ошибки `failed: cache mode is 'only-if-cached' but no cached response is available`.

Comment: что такое ваш "локальный пакет"? это пакет из поднятого локально реестра? это пакет из монорепозитория? это что-то ещё?

Comment: @nörbörnën мой пакет это open-source репозиторий github, который я склонировал

Comment: `npm install /path/to/clone`?